# MVC multiple results from SQL database not working correctly

Tags: c#, sql, .net, model-view-controller

Good morning,

I have been learning MVC .NET over the weekend and I'm trying to get data from a database but the results are not displaying:

I am using the following code:

```
public class ListClientsController : Controller
{
    private string QueryString;
    private string myConnectionString;
    public List<ListClients> models = new List<ListClients>();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        bool iterate = true;
        string iname = "";
        string isurname = "";
        int iIDNO = 0;

        QueryString = "select FirstName, Surname, IDNumber from [iDtB].[dbo].[Clients]";
        myConnectionString = "Data Source=<name>\\SQLEXPRESS01;Integrated Security=SSPI";
        SqlConnection iDtBData = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);
        iDtBData.Open();
        SqlCommand SQLCMD = new SqlCommand(QueryString, iDtBData);
        SqlDataReader Reader = SQLCMD.ExecuteReader();

        Reader.Read();
        while (iterate)
        {
            try
            {
                iname = Reader["FirstName"].ToString();
                isurname = Reader["Surname"].ToString();
                int.TryParse(Reader["IDNumber"].ToString(), out iIDNO);

                models.Add(new ListClients
                {
                    Name = iname,
                    Surname = isurname,
                    IDNO = iIDNO
                });

                Reader.NextResult();
            }
            catch
            {
                iterate = false;
            }
        }
        Reader.Close();
        iDtBData.Close();

        return View(models);
    }
}
```

For some reason I get this result:

[MVC Client results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBCGv.png)

Now notably, I understand that I am getting "0" for ID number due to mismatching fields, I don't understand why I can't get multiple results to display.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't actually reading all of the results returned from the query.  NextResult() returns the next result set, not the next record. Replace it with Read() and you should start getting all of the results.

I'd also eliminate the Try/Catch loop as that will prevent you from seeing any errors that do occur. Plus, Read returns a true/false to let you know if it read a record or not making eliminating it easy.

```
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            try
            {
                iname = Reader["FirstName"].ToString();
                isurname = Reader["Surname"].ToString();
                int.TryParse(Reader["IDNumber"].ToString(), out iIDNO);

                models.Add(new ListClients
                {
                    Name = iname,
                    Surname = isurname,
                    IDNO = iIDNO
                });
        }
```

I'd also recommend taking a look at how to use the using statement (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to improve handling of the connection and the data reader.